# Profile a WPF + WCF + EF app

Tags: c#, entity-framework, profiling

I've lately read about the MvcMiniProfiler, which I found really useful. However, we are developing a WPF app, so we can not use that (we are using WPF, WCF and Entity Framework with an Oracle DB, with the Devart EF provider).

What would be the easiest (most lightweight, smallest footprint) solution to profile our app constantly while developing? I would specifically be interested in how many and what SQL queries are sent to the DB during a WCF call, and how long do they take. Maybe this is completely unrelated to WPF and WCF, and what I need is just an EF profiler. And I am looking for a simple solution, even that would be acceptable, if the profile data was written out to the Debug window.

Comment: Yes, something as unobtrusive as the MvcMiniProfiler but that can be attached to (say) a WCF layer would be just... awesome. Especially if the output can be imported into Excel or somesuch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend reading Julie Lerman's [Profiling Database Activity in the Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx).  It walks through how to set up tracing, as well as some commercial profiling options, such as the [Entity Framework Profiler](http://efprof.com/).

This, combined with the standard Visual Studio profilers, will cover all three of your cases.  That being said, a good memory profiler (such as [SciTech's](http://memprofiler.com/)) can also be useful when working with the WPF application, in particular, as it's possible (easy?) to create memory leaks in WPF applications.

Comment: Thanks for the links and the suggestions. Actually the Devart EF provider comes with a profiling tool (called dbMonitor) similiar to the EF Pofiler. So the least effort solution seems to be to constantly run the dbMonitor during development.